# overpass api - query nodes with substring in any tag

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

How can I get all nodes with a specific string in any tag?

for example, this gives all nodes with mystring in tag:name:

```
http://overpass.osm.rambler.ru/cgi/interpreter?data=node[name~mystring](around:50000,50.10707,8.76040);out%2050;
```

but I want all nodes with mystring in ANY tags. I dont know how to "wildcard" the tag-name.

Thx, Tom

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Unfortunately, this is not yet possible in the Overpass API. But as far as I know, it is a feature that is currently been worked on.</strike> See this ticket on github for more info about how to do this with a regular expression search on the tag key: https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/59

Comment: This feature is available now! Please check github issue 59 for details and examples (link: see above).